# Redirecting one domain to another domains sub directory

Tags: dns, subdomain, redirect

I have been looking around on google and have had no luck.

What am I trying to accomplish: I am trying to take my "domain1.com" and redirect it to "domain2.com/foo.php" is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this PHP code to your index.php page, It will send a instant redirect

```
<?php header("location: http://domain2.com/foo.php"); ?>
```